# How to use Watin 64-bit with MSIE 32-bit

Tags: internet-explorer, winapi, 64-bit, watin

I have a C#-application running on Windows 7. I am using Watin to test some flash and quicktime movies in Internet Explorer. I am running in x64 mode due to some memory limitations I encountered in x86-mode. So I run my application which uses Watin, which starts MSIE. Watin starts the 64-bit version of MSIE. So far so good.

The problem is, flash and quicktime do not seem to work in MSIE 64-bit, so testing playing of movies will not work.

What must be done to run my C# application in 64-bit mode but to get Watin to run MSIE in 32-bit mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same problem with silverlight. If you have Silverlight in your application it doesn't load in IE x64.